# Producing list of contents in CSS looking awkward

Tags: html, css

I am trying to produce the following list in CSS/HTML from scratch:

[image]

Unfortunately, I ran into a few issue with absolute positioning, the elements seem to be on top of each other.

How do I use relative or flexboxes positioning to fix this?

```css
.contact-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
}

.contact-container:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.contact-avatar-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.contact-avatar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.contact-online-status {
  background-color: #41dc21;
  height: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 15px;
  left: 45px;
  width: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.contact-name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 70px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.contact-last-known-interaction {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 70px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgb(147, 147, 147);
}

.contact-call-button {
  height: 34px;
}

.contact-call-button .phone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  fill: rgb(57, 220, 12);
  font-size:16px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-list-container">
  <div class="contact-container">
    <div class="contact-avatar-container">
      <div class="contact-avatar" style="background: url(&quot;https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579192181049-2aa87e49df2a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60&quot;) 0% 0% / cover;"></div>
      <div class="contact-online-status"></div>
      <div class="contact-name">Abul Philip</div>
      <div class="contact-last-known-interaction">Last spoke Mar 27</div>
      <div class="contact-call-button"><svg viewBox="0 0 14 14" class="phone">
          <path d="m13.76 12.32-.38.54v.05.06c-1.41 2-5.42 1-9-2.28s-5.3-7.55-3.89-9.56v-.06l.07-.07.38-.52a1.15 1.15 0 0 1 1.77-.12l1.9 1.75a1.59 1.59 0 0 1 .27 2l-1.28 1.89a16.23 16.23 0 0 0 2.27 2.52 15.17 15.17 0 0 0 2.66 2l1.28-1.84a1.15 1.15 0 0 1 1.78-.12l1.89 1.75a1.58 1.58 0 0 1 .28 2.01z"></path>
        </svg></div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-avatar-container">
      <div class="contact-avatar" style="background: url(&quot;https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579192181049-2aa87e49df2a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60&quot;) 0% 0% / cover;"></div>
      <div class="contact-online-status"></div>
      <div class="contact-name">John Smith</div>
      <div class="contact-last-known-interaction">Became friends Mar 27</div>
      <div class="contact-call-button"><svg viewBox="0 0 14 14" class="phone">
          <path d="m13.76 12.32-.38.54v.05.06c-1.41 2-5.42 1-9-2.28s-5.3-7.55-3.89-9.56v-.06l.07-.07.38-.52a1.15 1.15 0 0 1 1.77-.12l1.9 1.75a1.59 1.59 0 0 1 .27 2l-1.28 1.89a16.23 16.23 0 0 0 2.27 2.52 15.17 15.17 0 0 0 2.66 2l1.28-1.84a1.15 1.15 0 0 1 1.78-.12l1.89 1.75a1.58 1.58 0 0 1 .28 2.01z"></path>
        </svg></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options.

Comment: Did you try using relative positioning or flexbox? What happened?

Comment: Indeed. Even though I was able to come up with a solution with minimal work, I would also like to see the absolute positioning swapped out for something better. I admit that it has its uses, but somehow using it makes me very nervous, especially from a responsive design standpoint.

Comment: The design in particular is for a desktop application with a a set minimum width and dynamic height. As a result, I thought that using relative positioning or flexbox might not be required, until I ran into the issues above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox, as commented here before, absolute positioning everything is poor practice. It will only destroy rather than make things beautiful if overused. Made an example for you using flexbox. Made a fiddle as example, hope it helps :)

**Also wrap information in parent elements, easier to style them then.**

```
      <div class="contact-information">
            <div class="contact-last-known-interaction">Became friends Mar 27</div>
            <div class="contact-name">John Smith</div>
      </div>
```

```css
/*parent to contact containers, we want flexed children hence -> display: flex;*/
.contact-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

/*parent to contact information, we also want the information to flex to easily handle it -> display: flex;*/
.contact-avatar-container {
  width: 60%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

/*flex the elements, some bigger than others depending on content*/
.contact-information {
    flex: 3;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

/*for example, this one is flexed less when the content is less*/
.contact-call-button {
  flex: .5;
}

.contact-avatar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.contact-online-status {
  background-color: #41dc21;
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 100%;
}


.contact-call-button svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid lightgreen;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.contact-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-list-container">
  <div class="contact-container">
  
    <div class="contact-avatar-container">
      <div class="contact-avatar" style="background: url(&quot;https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579192181049-2aa87e49df2a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60&quot;) 0% 0% / cover;"></div>
      <div class="contact-online-status"></div>
      <div class="contact-information">
            <div class="contact-last-known-interaction">Last spoke Mar 27</div>
            <div class="contact-name">Abul Philip</div>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-call-button"><svg viewBox="0 0 14 14" class="phone">
          <path d="m13.76 12.32-.38.54v.05.06c-1.41 2-5.42 1-9-2.28s-5.3-7.55-3.89-9.56v-.06l.07-.07.38-.52a1.15 1.15 0 0 1 1.77-.12l1.9 1.75a1.59 1.59 0 0 1 .27 2l-1.28 1.89a16.23 16.23 0 0 0 2.27 2.52 15.17 15.17 0 0 0 2.66 2l1.28-1.84a1.15 1.15 0 0 1 1.78-.12l1.89 1.75a1.58 1.58 0 0 1 .28 2.01z"></path>
        </svg></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="contact-avatar-container">
      <div class="contact-avatar" style="background: url(&quot;https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579192181049-2aa87e49df2a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60&quot;) 0% 0% / cover;"></div>
      <div class="contact-online-status"></div>
      <div class="contact-information">
            <div class="contact-last-known-interaction">Became friends Mar 27</div>
            <div class="contact-name">John Smith</div>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-call-button"><svg viewBox="0 0 14 14" class="phone">
          <path d="m13.76 12.32-.38.54v.05.06c-1.41 2-5.42 1-9-2.28s-5.3-7.55-3.89-9.56v-.06l.07-.07.38-.52a1.15 1.15 0 0 1 1.77-.12l1.9 1.75a1.59 1.59 0 0 1 .27 2l-1.28 1.89a16.23 16.23 0 0 0 2.27 2.52 15.17 15.17 0 0 0 2.66 2l1.28-1.84a1.15 1.15 0 0 1 1.78-.12l1.89 1.75a1.58 1.58 0 0 1 .28 2.01z"></path>
        </svg></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were missing styling for your outermost container. Also, you had a contact container, but multiple avatar containers inside it. I have separated out your contacts into their own containers and applied a grid to the list container.

Edit: Also, I realize that the phone icon is not fully in line with the rest of the elements, but I did not attempt to fix it because the CSS seems like a house of cards with all those absolute positions and `top`, `left`, `right` adjustments.

Edit 2: I added some flexboxes and slightly modified the HTML to see how it looks. Hope it helps!

```css
.contact-list-container {
  display: grid;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.contact-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: start;
  padding: 1em;
}

.contact-container:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.contact-avatar-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact-name-state-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: start;
}

.contact-controls-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact-avatar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.contact-online-status {
  background-color: #41dc21;
  height: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  align-self: start;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.contact-name {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.contact-last-known-interaction {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgb(147, 147, 147);
}

.contact-call-button .phone {
  fill: rgb(57, 220, 12);
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-list-container">
  <div class="contact-container">
    <div class="contact-avatar-container">
      <div class="contact-avatar" style="background: url(&quot;https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579192181049-2aa87e49df2a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60&quot;) 0% 0% / cover;"></div>
      <div class="contact-online-status"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-name-state-container">
      <div class="contact-last-known-interaction">Last spoke Mar 27</div>
      <div class="contact-name">Abul Philip</div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-controls-container">
      <div class="contact-call-button"><svg viewBox="0 0 14 14" class="phone">
          <path d="m13.76 12.32-.38.54v.05.06c-1.41 2-5.42 1-9-2.28s-5.3-7.55-3.89-9.56v-.06l.07-.07.38-.52a1.15 1.15 0 0 1 1.77-.12l1.9 1.75a1.59 1.59 0 0 1 .27 2l-1.28 1.89a16.23 16.23 0 0 0 2.27 2.52 15.17 15.17 0 0 0 2.66 2l1.28-1.84a1.15 1.15 0 0 1 1.78-.12l1.89 1.75a1.58 1.58 0 0 1 .28 2.01z"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-container">
    <div class="contact-avatar-container">
      <div class="contact-avatar" style="background: url(&quot;https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579192181049-2aa87e49df2a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60&quot;) 0% 0% / cover;"></div>
      <div class="contact-online-status"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-name-state-container">
      <div class="contact-last-known-interaction">Became friends Mar 27</div>
      <div class="contact-name">John Smith</div>
    </div>

    <div class="contact-controls-container">
      <div class="contact-call-button"><svg viewBox="0 0 14 14" class="phone">
          <path d="m13.76 12.32-.38.54v.05.06c-1.41 2-5.42 1-9-2.28s-5.3-7.55-3.89-9.56v-.06l.07-.07.38-.52a1.15 1.15 0 0 1 1.77-.12l1.9 1.75a1.59 1.59 0 0 1 .27 2l-1.28 1.89a16.23 16.23 0 0 0 2.27 2.52 15.17 15.17 0 0 0 2.66 2l1.28-1.84a1.15 1.15 0 0 1 1.78-.12l1.89 1.75a1.58 1.58 0 0 1 .28 2.01z"></path>
        </svg></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```